# Parsing out a grouping of parentheses with ruby regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to get an array of tokens such as `"((token 1))"`, `"((token 2))"`.  I have the following code:

```
sentence = "I had a ((an adjective)) sandwich for breakfast today. It oozed all over my ((a body part)) and ((a noun))."

token_arr = sentence.scan(/\(\(.*\)\)/)
# => ["((an adjective))", "((a body part)) and ((a noun))"]
```

The above code does not stop the match when it runs into the first occurrence of `"))"` in the sentence `"It oozed..."`.  I think I need a negative lookahead operator, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: So you only want the first match?

Answer (score 1):

Typical problem. Use non-greedy quantifier.

```
sentence.scan(/\(\(.*?\)\)/)
```

Alternatively, replace `/./` with "things other than `")"`":

```
sentence.scan(/\(\([^)]*\)\)/)
```

Comment: Note that the second option will reject `((something (bracketed) other thing))`. The 2 options are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

try this regex which will only pull non round brackets from the matched inner text

`[(]{2}([^()]*)[)]{2}`

[image]

[image]

Comment: from where you found the such pic? I am impressed. I am also learning ruby regex. so your help might give me a good start.

Comment: @ Priti I used debuggex.com which is a bit faster and more realtime then regexper.com. But they both to about the same thing. Really handy for seeing how a regex works.

Comment: @Priti: IMO, those diagrams are pretty and useless. Regex also encodes the behaviour of the regex engine, which is not shown in the diagrams.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Debuggex currently supports the javascript engine. While it's not captured in the static image, you can step through the regex using sliders to get insight on what's going on in the engine. I'd love to hear any more feedback you have.

Comment: I find those diagrams to be very useful for understanding the overall flow for a regex especially complex ones. When there round brackets are nested 3 or 4 deep and intermixed with the square and squiggly brackets and multiple 'or' conditions the regex just starts to look like a mess of random characters. Aside from helping regex veterans, they also help people who are new to regex more quickly understand how a regex works.

Kudos to  you if your able to read a regex and understand it quickly.

Comment: You're right the diagram is only half of the equation the other half is understanding how the engine works. That being said, I think a diagram is a great place to start, especially for a Q&A site.